# angular2 gulp task is compiling but with errors

Tags: typescript, angular

I am working on a gulpfile where I want to compile the angular 2 app but I get some errors:

[image]

What do they mean by it does not exist on type "..." and how do I make it exist? Where nativeWindow is a `window.service.ts` looks like this:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Imports Section:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import {window} from 'angular2/src/facade/browser';

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Service Class:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor Method Section:
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor() { }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public Properties Section:
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    get nativeWindow(): Window {
        return window;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your screenshot. What type has `preferences`? Also `window` is supposed to be your service?

Comment: Also, why do you even have a service that returns the `window` object? I don't see the use case for this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get says that the property `range` for example cannot be found on `preferences`. The same applies for your `WindowService`. In your getter you return the `window` object and in your component you try to access `offerResults` on that `window` object. This property does not make any sense on the `window` object because this object represents an open window in the browser and I would not store any data in that object.