# Angular2: No best common type exists among return expressions

Tags: typescript, angular

Trying to compile my typescript with gulp but I'll get the following error:

`No best common type exists among return expressions.`

Where the code is a `for` loop which looks like this:

```
   getIndexInCompareList(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.compare.length; i++) {
        if (this.compare[i].resource.id == result.resource.id) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just a few tips: If you use Typescript why dont you use a proper function signature? Meaning to declare what the function returns. Also use `let` instead of `var` and use explicit types, e.g. for your parameters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @günter-zöchbauer mentioned, your function does return two different types. If you really want to return a number in one case and otherwise a boolean you could use `any` as your return value for the function to fix this issue.

However, as many other functions such as `indexOf` return numbers only even if the value was not found I would suggest you do the same. In your case you could also return `-1` if the item was not found. This way you can be explicit about your types and also provide a clear interface for others.

```
function getIndexInCompareList(result): number {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.compare.length; i++) {
        if (this.compare[i].resource.id == result.resource.id) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Could you also help me out on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439197/angular2-gulp-task-is-compiling-but-with-errors

Answer (score 4):

`return i;` returns a `number`, `return false returns a`boolean`

You might need to apply an explicit return type `: any` at the function signature. (not sure, I'm not using TS myself)